# How to make POSBOX work with Nginx and SSL

Tags: nginx, odoo-10

I'm having trouble getting my Posboxes to work with my remote Odoo v10 server with Nginx and SSL.

I have tried configuring Nginx to send request to /pos/ over http. This results in a Mixed Content error in Safari and Chrome.
As I am using iPads, I cannot make Safari ignore this. This is also the result when I try to serve the /pos/ directory over https.
This results in the browser not being able to connect to the Posbox.

I've read and tried the solutions in these GitHub issues, with no success:

https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/2031
https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/3156

Does anyone have a working Nginx config example for use with Odoo 10?

Answer (score 0):

if you are still facing this issue, then here is the fix. Please go through this blog:

https://webkul.com/blog/serve-odoo-posbox-over-https

I have also upgraded the ODOO POSBOX base image so that it will have nginx pre-installed in it, which can be easily connects with ODOO served over https.

Download Link : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1dx-UuV9AOYbWZSNG1GVjBPOTQ

I hope it will work.